# Jhipster microservice Java client api call error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster, resttemplate

We have deployed a JHipster app in microservice architecture. We are using the OAuth option, in which I am a newbee. The front end works fine. But now we dont know how to debug the java client that accesses the restful endpoints. We are using nginx to implement ssh and hide the port, in case that is relevant.

Code is:

```
    String plainCreds = "myuser:mypassword";
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    String url = "https://mysite/api/my-entity/1111";
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
    String response = response.getBody();
```

The response is

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use uaa and a gateway.

Your code must authenticate against `/api/authenticate` using a POST and JSON payload (see `UserJWTControllerIntTest.testAuthorize()`) to get a token.

Once you have a token, you must send it with each request using `Authorization` HTTP header with `Bearer` prefix: `Authorization : Bearer c123aaacr`

Comment: Oh, thank you. That shows how little I know. Tried Postman curl -X POST \
  https://myrul/api/authenticate \
  -H 'authorization: Basic Z3JlZy5mY2E6aGVyIFRoZW1lMWJyYXllZDJjYW4zYTRkaXNocmFnJWphbSRhLWdleXNlcg==' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: 8c2ad2e7-333b-9a56-6d61-c612070f4200' and get "Request method 'POST' not supported",

Comment: Also tried using OAuth2RestTemplate. Got the same "Request method POST not supported" message. Google suggests it is something to do with my request, but I cant see anything wrong.

Comment: Your payload is not JSON and why all these headers, just do what is done in the unit test JWTControllerIntTest.testAuthorize()

Comment: Gael, sorry, I cant convert UserJWTControllerIntTest.testAuthorize() to what I need for a simple client POJO, with no Jhipster and Spring. I cant find documentation on what my test curl should look like. My Postman code is now: curl -X POST https://myurl/api/authenticate -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{??}'. If I knew what ?? was, that would that get me a token?

Comment: Correct. UserJWTController.authorize() is mapped on /api/authenticate and takes a LoginVM as a parameter. JSON serialized of LoginVM is {"username": "xxx", "password: "yyy", "rememberMe": false}

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got to work.

When authenticating against the UAA version of the microservices architecture 
- end point is https://myAddress.../myApp.../oauth/token
- Content-Type in header = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body has grant_type = password, username and password.

I left my use of UAA out of the question - did not see that made important in the docs.

With thanks to Jon Ruddell.